# What are the best enhancements for a rapier?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, optimization, eberron

I am playing a character whose base class is a swashbuckler. But I did not optimize it to be a great warrior because for once I decided to rather invest in relationships and feats related to eberron, and I enjoy playing this way. But as a consequence, my fighting power did not improve at all while passing levels; my base attack bonus did, but I am still dealing (1D6+strength bonus+int bonus) damage as when I was a low level.

We recently seized some gold pieces and have the possibility of buying magical enhancements for our weapons, so I am looking for the best way of improving my damage rate. Do you know of special rapiers, or of effects that are especially effective on a rapier?

**EDIT:** I think I should give additional details on what books are allowed. The universe is *Eberron*, so imports from others universes like *Forgotten Realms*, *Faerun*, *Oriental Adventures*, are not allowed. In *Eberron* the DM proposed the use of the *Action Points* and *DragonMarks* system which already adds improvements to the gameplay on its own, and as a consequence, other alternative gameplays like *psionnics* and related (for example the *collision* effect) are not allowed. Finally, some books a little too much unbalanced like the *Tome of Battle* and *Sword and Fist* and all dragon fight related books are disallowed... which still lets a lot of books allowed, I think to all *complete xxxx* supplementals, most compendiums, plus the base rulebooks and anything else matching the general spirit of being evenly balanced and not being part of a specific universe or additional ruleset system beside Eberron.

Since this question could possibly be used as a reference for another swashbuckler not having the same constraints, don't hesitate proposing though, even if I can't use it, it's still interesting knowing it exists.

Some additionnal details on myself now. I am currently *swashbuckler 5/dragonmark heir 2/duellist 1*. For further progression I am aiming *swashbuckler 5/dragonmark heir 4/duellist 3/blade of Orien N*. I have the dragonmark of passage and I use it a lot to teleport in combat. I also invested a lot of skillpoints in movement skilltricks and in movement or relational skills like tumble, jump, balance, diplomacy, sense motive, bluff.. 
Without wearing magic items, my current abilities are DEX-18, STR-12, INT-14, CON-14, WIS-10, CHA-10

There is already a lot of replies, thanks a lot everybody, I apologize for not having given more details earlier. I will let the question open for a while since I also need time to explore all of your suggestions.

Comment: Exactly how much do you have to spend? What level are you buying for?

Comment: I did not gave those details because I am looking as well for a long term continuous improving plan. I am taking my 8th level, and have around 8000 GP to spend. Most of my equipments slots are free, so I could also for example buy a +2 INT item to get +1 on dmgs and INT related throws. Must also mention that we have an artificer in the party that can get us prices reductions or apply the enhancements himself depending on which is the more interesting.

Comment: How are you fighting? Two Weapon Combat or single weapon?

Comment: single weapon combat

Comment: Get Enlarge cast on you (moves the Rapier up to the next size category for damage) Not a weapon enhancement, so not answering directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Counterintuitively,**

## Avoid Weapon Special Abilities that Inflict Damage

If your PC has been taking feats like Favored in House (*ECS* 53), and Least Dragonmark (mark of finding (*ECS* 64)) (*ECS* 53), and Skill Focus (Bluff) (*PH* 100) so he can better make [Seduce to Learn Secret](https://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/cwc/20070227x) checks while the other PCs have been specializing in monster murdering, and they realize you aren't contributing much in a fight, explain that you'll need their help. As a swashbuckler (who doesn't cast spells) you were going to need it anyway. That's not an insult but a fact of mid- and high-level play.

You'll need their help because the first weapon special ability you add to your rapier is *spell storing* (*DMG* 225) (+1 bonus). No other weapon special ability scales for damage as well as it does because it scales with your *party*, one of whom should be happy to refill your *+1 spell storing rapier* free of charge at the end of a slow adventuring day. If you must fill your own tank, take ranks in the Use Magic Device skill and load your *+1 spell storing rapier* using a *wand of combust* [evoc] (*SpC* 50) (2nd-level spell at caster level 10) (300 gp/charge) or a *wand of vampiric touch* [necro] (*PH* 298) (3rd-level spell at caster level 20) (900 gp/charge) or a wand of another spell that the Comments will inevitably suggest.

It sounds like you're in a game wherein sources of magic items are restricted. If you aren't, also consider the weapon special ability *bloodstone* (*MIC* 29) (+1 bonus), which is like the weapon special ability *spell storing* that only holds the spell *vampiric touch* but the *touch* is modified by the feat Empower Spell (*PH* 93) for free. Seriously. Then add the weapon special ability *power storing* (*MIC* 40) (+1 bonus) if there's a psion available; my unfamiliarity with psionics means I don't know what's best, but there *must* be something awesome and Eberron is psionics-friendly. Then virtually guarantee your attack hits by adding the weapon special ability *impaling* (*MIC* 37) (+1 bonus).

If you are confined to the *Dungeon Master's Guide* for your weapon, the only other serious choices for damage are the weapon special abilities *bane* (*DMG* 224) (+1 bonus), picking whatever the DM's throwing at you a lot, and *holy* (*DMG* 225) (+2 bonus) or, y'know, *unholy* (*DMG* 226) (+2 bonus) if you're an *evil* swashbuckler: a lot of your foes will be evil (or good) anyway; punish them for it. If chasing *just* damage buy the weapon special abilities *magebane* (*CAr* 143-4) (+1 bonus) and *vampiric* (*MIC* 45) (+2 bonus) if allowed.

The flat +5 damage from the weapon special ability *collision* (*MIC* 31) (+2 bonus) is the best you're going to get, but also consider, if it's permitted, the weapon special ability *fierce* (*AE* 96) (+2 bonus) that lets the weapon's wielder to take a penalty to his Armor Class up to his Dexterity bonus to add the the penalty's absolute value as a bonus to the weapon's damage.

Although others may disagree, most of the other damaging effects from the *DMG* and elsewhere inflict energy damage that a high level creature's energy resistance will easily absorb, employ effects high level foes are often immune to (e.g. ability damage and ability drain, critical hits, negative energy effects), or have saving throw DCs that are too low to be viable.

**Effects That Don't Inflict Damage, But Take a Look**
The weapon special ability *dispelling* (*MIC* 33) (+1 bonus) et. al. will make you popular with your group even if you aren't inflicting a lot of damage. The same goes for the weapon special ability *revealing* (*MIC* 42) (+1 bonus), which eliminates miss chances for your party; in high-level play miss chances are commonplace, and everyone will thank you even if you hit only once.

The *elemental power* weapon special abilities from *DMG2* 254-5 et. al. range from a +1 bonus to a +4 bonus and permit summoning of an elemental of increasing size based on the bonus purchased. Being an elemental-summoning swashbuckler may sound strange, but the value of minions with cool powers can't be overstated--ask any necromancer.

I don't like abilities that allow saving throws nor do I like abilities relying on critical hits, but the weapon special ability *prismatic burst* (*MIC* 40) (30,000 gp) is an exception to both. The flat cost means it's possible to add it to a weapon that's already full of other bonuses. The weapon special ability *sending* (*LE* 152) (+4 bonus) is also valuable, despite only activating on a natural 20 and a successful critical roll; a no-saving-throw teleport effect *versus* a high-level foe is more likely to remove him from battle than almost any other effect, although by the time this is avaialable most foes should have a way of returning to the battlefield shortly.

I've not heard of a DM actually allowing the weapon special ability *smoking* (*LD* 180) (+1 bonus), but I suggest it because it exists. It's a defensive ability, but a spectactular one, and defensive abilities keep you alive long enough to use offensive abilities. The weapon special ability *spellblade* (*PG* 120) (6,000 gp) is just as cool; pick a targeted spell the DM loves, ignore it, and even huck it back at the caster.

The weapon special ability *Keeper's fang* (*ECS* 266) (+4 bonus) renders creatures you kill with the weapon unable to return from the dead *via* the spells "*resurrection*, *raise dead*, *reincarnate*, or similar effects"; the weapon becomes evil and makes you look like a jerk to some folks, but this is such a powerful ability in any typical *Dungeons and Dragons* campaign that its utility can't be ignored.

**Don't Neglect Accessories!**
A broken weapon made from aurorum (*BE* 38) (+4,000 gp) can be made whole as full-round action, but a weapon made from riverine (*Sto* 128) (+2,000 gp/lb.) is just immune to damage.

A weapon made from morghuth-iron (*AE* 14) (+4,000 gp) is constantly naturally poisonous, but the poison's saving throw DC is low, the weapon's wielder takes a -1 penalty to attack rolls and damage rolls with the weapon, and many high-level creatures are straight-up immune to poison. This is, however, far cheaper than many effects, and there's no use limit.

A weapon with the template pitspawned (*DMG2* 278) (+1,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the wielder a +2 bonus to critical rolls.

A wand chamber (*Du* 34) (100 gp; 0 lbs.) is a space in the weapon for a wand which can be used without drawing the wand; perfect if you've ranks in the Use Magic Device skill. A hilt hollow (*Du* 33) (300 gp; 0 lbs.) is a space in the weapon for a potion which must be extracted but it's easier than normal. Get both. An oil chamber (*Du* 33-4) (1,000 gp; 0 lbs.) is expensive, but can hold an *oil of greater magic weapon* [trans] (*PH* 251-2) (3rd-level spell at caster level 20) (*DMG* 230) (3,000 gp; 0.1 lbs.) or ghostoil (AE 34) (50 gp; 1 lb.). A triple weapon capsule retainer (*CAd* 121-2) (450 gp; 0 lbs.) holds 3 alchemical weapon capsules (*CAd* 122), which do everything from more damage to silvering your weapon on the fly.

You'll want a weapon with at least a +3 enhancement bonus (*not* just a +1 weapon with at least 1 additional +2 bonus or 2 additional +1 bonus weapon special abilities!) if planning to attach the most powerful augment crystals (*MIC* 221). Start with the *crystal of return* (least) (*MIC* 65) (300 gp; 0 lbs.) now if you've not the feat Quick Draw (*PH* 98) or another way to draw a weapon as a free action. Purchase more augment crystals as needed for the campaign.

**Suggestions**
All bets are off if the campaign allows more sources than these.

- A *+1 bane (humans) holy spell-storing adamantine rapier* (53,320 gp; 3 lbs.) if you can only use the *Dungeon Master's Guide*.
- A *+1 bloodstone collision dispelling impaling prismatic burst spell-storing vampiric adamantine rapier* (195,320 gp; 3 lbs.) if you can use the *Dungeon Master's Guide* and the *Magic Items Compendium*. *Perspective:* This weapon costs nearly *two tons* of gold.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of info, thanks a lot \o/. I am going to read carefully. The suggestion about seduce to learn secret is brilliant, I am favored in house, and have two levels of "dragonmark heir", and already alot of diplomacy and bluff, but unfortunately only CHA 10. As for allowed rulebooks, the DM forbids other universes and too cheated rulebooks like "sword and fist", "dragonlance", "tome of battle", but allows regular suplementals like "complete warrior" or "complete scoundrel" and "magic compendium"

Comment: _Seduce to learn secret_ and _fierce_ have been accepted by my GM. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

The most useful rapier enchantment is [*Keen*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#keen). A rapier alteady has a good critical chance and doubling it is really advantageous. This allows you to deal double damage against most creatures - conveniently, it's the ones you can apply your precision damage to.
(As @KRyan reminds me, since *Keen* is a +1 enhancement, a *Scabbard of Keen Edges* is way more convenient on a heavily enchanted weapon.)

Other good enchantments to go for if you want to follow this strategy are ones that give you a flat amount of damage, like [*Collision*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/items/weapons.htm#collision).

If you plan on charging a lot and if you can sneak in (I mean, ask your DM!) a 3.0, Forgotten Realms enchantment, *Shining South* has the *Valorous* weapon enchantment, doubling your damage on a charge.

I also found some other good options [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=205218). It was nice noticing how their first three ideas were also mine. Their list includes:

- *Enfeebling* (Strenght damage on a critical) [*Book of Vile Darkness*]
- *Sudden Stunning* (Stun chance that scales with charisma and level [PH2]
- *Brilliant Energy* (Again, useless against Construccts and Undead but... you're already uneffective against them)

Comment: Remember though that the Improved Critical feat and Keen don't stack, so you need to decide which way you're going - whether weapon enchants being way more expensive is important or having a spare feat is important.

Comment: A *scabbard of keen edges*, at high level, is cheaper than *keen*. Specifically, it's cheaper than adding *keen* to a +4-equivalent weapon. A feat should probably be worth more than 16k if you're choosing feats wisely.

Comment: @mxyzplk I avoided mentioning that option because the querent is looking for items that help him increase his damage output while leaving his feat slots free.

Comment: Unfortunately I am pretty sure my DM will never allow imports from other universes like forgotten realms or psionnics, since we already benefit from the specificities of eberron. I will check the other things later since it is mostly NSFW content. As for improved critical I already considered taking it, but I think I will better follow KRyan suggestion and keep my feat for something else. Anyway thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

**Well...**

The thing about this is that most weapon enchantments are chosen in an effort to improve a weapon's *utility*, not its damage. If you just wanna add damage on, then your +1's are gonna be the kings of the day - *screaming* and *caustic* deserve a particular mention for being difficult to resist. They don't multiply on a critical hit, but as odd as this is going to sound to say, rapiers aren't all that great for crit-fishing.

Beyond elemental damage, a *scabbard of keen edges* will help you get critical hits more often (though, again, you're not a dedicated crit fisher so don't break the bank trying). Consider an alignment enhancement if you commonly fight enemies of a specific alignment or subtype - *anarchic* if you usually fight drow and demons, for example. The *force* enhancement will help with pesky DR issues as well.

For utility, it's hard to beat the combo of *eager* and *warning*, which cap out at a whopping +7 to your initiative, +2 damage in the first round of combat, and a free quick draw.

You should also check out the weapon crystals found in *Magic Item Compendium*; they're sort-of-enhancements that don't take up an enhancement slot!

Comment: Yeah I am looking for improving utility as well, but improving damage is the main goal. For example I was considering effects that add 1D6 fire damage, but I will take a look at all your suggestions. As for the alignment option, I can't tell for the moment because the campaign has not really started: there is indeed a mainstream, but until now that was more like a succession of non directly related one shots.

Answer (score 2):

Get specialized weapons for the enemies you're fighting. If you fight lots of evil outsiders and undead, for example, the "Sacred" weapon quality will be very good for you. If you fight lots of orcs, get an orc bane weapon. If you fight lots of golems, get an admantine rapier with construct bane. Bane weapons increase the enhancement bonus of the weapon by two, and give an extra 2d6 damage if the enemy is right.

You can alternatively invest in weapon crystals per Magic Item Compendium. Many of them offer situational damage boosts or other great perks, like life keeping.

Answer (score -1):

In a campaign iv'e played i had a swashbuckler that was all about skills related to acrobatics (tumble, jump etc.).

As a consequence I found myself facing the same problem. Because role-playing-wise it was built heavily on strength of purpose and rascal-ish righteousness (chaotic good). I found my answer in *Weapons of Legacy* and role played his rapier getting buffs in the form of extra damage dice, bonuses to intelligence, and intimidation rolls (related to his characteristics and alignment) scaling up with his level.

Because the swashbuckler is a class with a lot of personality this seems to me to be your best option for dealing decent damage while keeping the flair of the iconic rapier on par with the rest of the party.

Also once you reach the requirement *Improved Critical* is extremely useful as a rapier's critical range is already 18-20.